# How to insert static contents next to variables in $_POST

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, plivo

How can I insert static phrases before and after $_POST variables? Here's the code that I'm using:

```
<?php
require_once '/home/example/public_html/sms/vendor/autoload.php';
use Plivo\RestAPI;
$auth_id = "MAM2IXMDVLNZI3xxxxxx";
$auth_token = "YmI0NmQyZWQ5MDcwNjEyNjc4ZTMxYjNhMmxxxxxx";

$p = new RestAPI($auth_id, $auth_token);

// Send a message
$params = array(
        'src' => 'AcmeLLC', // Sender's phone number with country code
        'dst' =>  $_POST["dst"], //Receiver's phone number with country code
        'text' => $_POST["text"], // Your SMS text message
        //'url' => 'http://example.com/sms.html', // The URL to which with the status of the message is sent
        'method' => 'POST' // The method used to call the url
    );
 // Send message
$response = $p->send_message($params);

// Print the response
echo "Response : ";
print_r ($response['response']);

// Print the Api ID
echo "<br> Api ID : {$response['response']['api_id']} <br>";

// Print the Message UUID
echo "Message UUID : {$response['response']['message_uuid'][0]} <br>";

?>
```

I wish to achieve something like this:

```
'text' => Hello, $_POST["name"] Thank you for registering. Your unique membership ID is $_POST["memid"] More details have been sent on $_POST["email"]
```

As you know this is obviously wrong since there are no hints to suggest whether some word are actually static and other are received from Gravity Forms via POST. How should I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
'text' => 'Hello'.$_POST["name"].'Thank you for registering. Your unique membership ID is'. $_POST["memid"] .'More details have been sent on'. $_POST["email"]
```

Enclose the text in single quotes.

Let me know if it works out.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked just perfectly! I knew the it had a simple answer but being a newbie in PHP this became a big accomplishment for me. :)

Comment: @ngrhd glad it helped you! Please mark the answer as correct :)